# How to find components of vector other than 90 degree between eachother

Tags: vectors

As from the Pythagoras theorem we can find the resolved parts of a vector (with given angle and magnitude) which makes angle 90 degree with each other.
How to find components of vector other than at right angle to each other i.e greater than 90 or smaller than 90.
any formula like Pythagoras that can do this??

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform thanks for your suggestion, i have seen Vector projection and law of cosines
Vector projection gives components at 90 degree while law of cosine is for finding the resultant from resolved parts. I did not found any clue.

Answer (score 1):

The components axes $x^\prime$ and $y^\prime$ are inclined by angle $\theta$.

Use the sine rule.

[image]